# How can I monitor an EMC VNXe3100 with Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, emc, emc-vnxe

I've "Googled" a lot and there's some stuff for other products (Clariion & Celerra).

I didn't find any Nagios plugin or script for VNXe.

I got the vnxe_alert.mib but it's really not convenient at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with EMC, but did you try [this](https://community.emc.com/message/633120#633120)?

Comment: Hi quanta.

Indeed, Unisphere Remote is a proper solution so I'll use it.
Thanks for this link.

Please, Let me know if there is anything available for Nagios.
I try to centralize everything for my monitoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that discussion thread, the VNXe only supports SNMP traps, so you aren't going to find a traditional polling-style Nagios plugin for it. There is also [link to a MIB](https://download.emc.com/downloads/DL40061_VNXe_Alert_MIB.mib) for the traps, in this thread, but I can't get it to load.

You can, however, set up snmptrapd and then use snmptt to translate traps into passive checks for nagios. It's a bit complicated, but it's doable. There are also some other options for getting snmp traps into nagios, shown on this [Nagios docs page](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/int-snmptrap.html).

They also mention writing a wrapper around the UEMCLI output, but I don't think anyone has done this yet. I would expect to see it show up in [the EMC category on Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Storage-Systems/SAN-and-NAS/EMC-Clarion).